# Упорядочить в запросе поле varchar как int

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table`
WHERE 1
GROUP BY `my_field`
ORDER BY `my_field` ASC

+++++++++++++++++
+ name  + use   +
+++++++++++++++++
+ ola   + 1288  +
+ masha + 1412  +
+ lera  + 175   +
+ lena  + 185   +
+ liza  + 274   +
+ katya + 3     +
+ sveta + 407   +
+ irina + 556   +
+++++++++++++++++
```

Делаю запрос к таблице, поле которое я упорядочил по возрастанию УПОРЯДОЧИВАЕТСЯ, но тип ячейки текстовый, а внутри цифры. Ест-но логично изменить тип поля на int и нет проблем. Но, в моем случае, нельзя менять тип поля.

Прошу объяснить, как написать запрос, что бы сортировка была как будь то бы тип полей числовой, и поле сортировалось исходя из этого

```
+++++++++++++++++
+ name  + use   +
+++++++++++++++++
+ katya +     3 +
+ lera  +   175 +
+ lena  +   185 +
+ liza  +   274 +
+ sveta +   407 +
+ irina +   556 +
+ ola   +  1288 +
+ masha +  1412 +
+++++++++++++++++
```

p.s. за название темы извиняюсь, не смог ни чего лучше придумать

Comment: Для MySQL можно использовать простейшее `ORDER BY 0+use`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(`my_field`, SIGNED INTEGER)
```

или

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(`my_field`, UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Comment: на некоторых web серверах почему то прокатывает не работает CONVERT ( там использую CAST )

Answer (score 0):

Используйте преобразование типа в `ORDER BY` для необходимой сортировки.